# Typo in Spivak’s Mechanics?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, differential, pullback, canonical-transformation

From Spivak's *Physics for Mathematicians, vol.1*:

> At this point, it might be nice to have a few concrete exzamples of canonical transfomrations
> $f:T^{*}M\to T^{*}M$. Canonical transformations are often defined in terms of the corresponding
> change of variables: given coordinates $(q,p)$ on the domain, we give a formula for the
> corresponding coordinates $$
> \begin{matrix}
>  Q^{i}=q^{i}\circ f \\
>  P_j = p_j\circ f
> \end{matrix} \qquad \text{with}\qquad
> \begin{matrix}
>  dQ^{i}=f^{*}(dq^{i})\\
>  dP_j=f^{*}(dp_j),
> \end{matrix}
> $$
> on the range. For example, in dimension $1$, we can consider $$
> Q=q+p\tau +\frac{1}{2}g\tau ^2,\qquad P=p+g\tau
> $$ for constants $g$ and $\tau$. Since $$
> dQ\wedge dP=f^{*}(dq+\tau dp)\wedge f^{*}dp=f^{*}(dq\wedge dp),
> $$ this is canonical transformation. Often, we don't even bother writing the $f^{*}$.

In the last string of equalities, shouldn’t $ f^*(dq + \tau dp)\wedge f^*dp $ instead read $(dq + \tau dp)\wedge dp$?

$Q, P, q, p$ are coordinate functions on $T^*M$, and $f:T^*M \rightarrow T^*M$.  If we have $Q=q+\tau p+\frac{1}{2}gt^2$ and $P=p+\tau g$, then $dQ=dq+\tau dp$ and $dP=dp$.  So $dQ\wedge dP=(dq+\tau dp)\wedge dp$.  On the other hand, since $Q=f^*q$ and $P=f^*p$, we have $dQ=f^*dq$ and $dP=f^*dp$. So $f^*dq=dq+\tau dp$, $f^*dp=dp$, and

[image: diagram]

Comment: No. Remember that $Q=f^*q$ and $P=f^*p$.

Comment: So $f^*dq = f^*(dq + \tau dp)$ ?

Comment: No, $f^*(\tau dp)\wedge f^*dp = (f^*\tau)(f^*dp\wedge f^*dp) = 0$.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I wasn't clear with my question: I agree the equalities are true.  I guess I'm wondering why he put it like that.  Are the following statements true?  (1a) $dQ = dq + \tau dp$ and $dP = dp$, therefore (1b) $dQ \wedge dP = (dq + \tau dp)\wedge dp$.  (2a) $dQ = f^*dq$ and $dP = f^*dp$, therefore (2b) $dQ \wedge dP = f^*dq \wedge f^*dp = f^*(dq \wedge dp)$.

Comment: He's defining $f(q,p) = (Q,P) = (q+p\tau+\frac12g\tau^2, p+g\tau)$. Neither of your statements is true.

Comment: Now I’m really confused.  (2a) follows from your first comment, (2b) follows from basic properties of the pullback and wedge product.

Comment: The confusion is that $(q,p)$ are being used, a priori, as coordinates on $T^*M$ in both domain and range. But from the equation $f(q,p)=(Q,P)$ we give $Q$ as a function of $q$ and $p$, so $dQ = d(q+p\tau+\frac12g\tau^2)$.

Comment: I understand that Spivak is implicitly assuming (q,p) are defined on both the domain and range of f.  (They would have to be if we’re defining $Q=f^*q$ and $P=f^*p$.). I’ve edited my question to include a diagram of how I’m thinking of everything.  Do you mind pointing out exactly what’s wrong with my picture.  As far as I can tell, it’s consistent with everything you’ve said so far.  I really appreciate your help- thanks again.